# How to limit count on a table

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to do a limit count or be able to find how many times a user has interacted with a site with a cap.
So if the amount of users reached a cap to give the maximum amount and if only a certain amount of users have visited that is under the cap i want to know that number as well with the date limiting on the 4th of January.

USERINSTANCE

| UserID | Instance | CapID | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 2 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 3 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 4 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 5 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 1 | row | 2 | 01/02/2022 |
| 6 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 2 | row | 2 | 01/02/2022 |
| 7 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 8 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 9 | row | 1 | 01/03/2022 |
| 10 | row | 1 | 01/03/2022 |
| 11 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 12 | row | 1 | 01/02/2022 |
| 13 | row | 1 | 01/03/2022 |
| 3 | row | 2 | 01/03/2022 |
| 4 | row | 2 | 01/03/2022 |
| 5 | row | 2 | 01/04/2022 |
| 6 | row | 2 | 01/04/2022 |
| 14 | row | 1 | 01/04/2022 |

CAPLIMIT

| LimitCap | capID | tracker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | sales |
| 5 | 2 | invite |

Desired results:

| Tracker | LimitCap | ActualCount | TotalCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | 10 | 10 | 14 |
| Invite | 5 | 4 | 6 |

Comment: It comes from a different table so i know i need to do an inner join to get The values but i am lost on how to do this

Comment: What is actualcount?

Comment: Actual count being how many are counted before the date constraint of 01/04/2022, showing how before 01/04/2022 there was only 4 users that alerted the capID

Comment: Could you do something like SUM(CASE WHEN date < '2022-01-04' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ActualCount, SUM(1) as TotalCount ..... GROUP BY tracker, limitCap

Answer (score 1):

So Michael has shown how to do a logical count via SUM & IFF, and then use LEAST to doing the capping.

There is also the inbuild function [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html) that is even more tidy to do this:

Thus with some CTE's for data:

```
with USERINSTANCE(UserID, Instance, CapID, date) as (
    select column1, column2, column3, to_date(column4, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from values
        (1  ,'row'  ,1, '01/02/2022'),
        (2  ,'row'  ,1, '01/02/2022'),
        (3  ,'row'  ,1, '01/02/2022'),
        (4  ,'row'  ,1, '01/02/2022'),
        (5  ,'row'  ,1, '01/02/2022'),
        (1  ,'row'  ,2, '01/02/2022'),
        (6  ,'row'  ,1, '01/02/2022'),
        (2  ,'row'  ,2, '01/02/2022'),
        (7  ,'row'  ,1, '01/02/2022'),
        (8  ,'row'  ,1, '01/02/2022'),
        (9  ,'row', 1, '01/03/2022'),
        (10,'row', 1, '01/03/2022'),
        (11,'row',  1, '01/02/2022'),
        (12,'row',  1, '01/02/2022'),
        (13,'row',  1, '01/03/2022'),
        (3  ,'row'  ,2, '01/03/2022'),
        (4  ,'row'  ,2, '01/03/2022'),
        (5  ,'row'  ,2, '01/04/2022'),
        (6  ,'row', 2, '01/04/2022'),
        (14,'row',  1, '01/04/2022')
), caplimit(limitcap, capid, tracker) as (
    select * from values
    (10, 1, 'sales'),
    (5, 2, 'invite')
)
```

and the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    c.tracker, 
    c.LimitCap, 
    LEAST(count_if(date < '2022-01-04'), c.LimitCap) AS ActualCount, 
    COUNT(Instance) AS TotalCount
FROM USERINSTANCE AS u
JOIN CAPLIMIT AS c 
    ON u.CapID = c.CapID
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

we get:

| TRACKER | LIMITCAP | ACTUALCOUNT | TOTALCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sales | 10 | 10 | 14 |
| invite | 5 | 4 | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT c.tracker, c.LimitCap, LEAST(SUM(IFF(date < '01/04/2022'::date, 1, 0)), c.LimitCap) AS ActualCount, COUNT(Instance) AS TotalCount
  FROM USERINSTANCE AS u
  JOIN CAPLIMIT AS c ON u.CapID = c.CapID
 GROUP BY c.tracker, c.LimitCap;
```